# Пагинация сделана через AJAX. Когда я хочу вернуться на прошлую страницу с помощью кнопки браузера «назад», это не работает. Как лучше это сделать?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я так понял, что нужно использовать функцию

```
$(window).on('popstate', function (event) {...}
```

И в ней сверять текущий url (который получился после нажатия на кнопку "Назад" в браузере) с прошлым (до кнопки "Назад"). Если поменялись GET параметры, но сам url такой же (location.pathname), то выполнять ajax на сервер и получать item'ы, учитывая текущий GET-параметр page (то есть, с нужным offset).

Но как получить прошлый url (до нажатия кнопки "Назад" в браузере)? Можно внести его в cookie, но ведь пользователь несколько раз может нажать кнопку "Назад" в браузере. Также, как и "Вперед".

Итак, вопрос - как получить прошлый url?

Comment: Надо работать с историей браузера https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: @KAGGDesign, как мне из истории достать прошлый url? Можно сделать go или forward, чтобы получить прошлый url, а потом вернуться обратно и сравнить текущий url с полученным - одинаковые ли get параметры или нет. И если нет, значит, пользователь перешел на другую страницу (использовал пагинацию). Так? Ну а как мне узнать - go или forward? Какая из них прошлая? Пользователь ведь мог нажать кнопку в браузере "Назад" или "Вперед". И от этого зависит, какая страница будет прошлой - та, что спереди, или та, что сзади.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете получить доступ к истории url - браузер не отдаёт эти сведения по соображениям безопасности. Но вы можете перехватывать клики на кнопках и делать replaceState или pushState в зависимости от вашей задачи, чтобы запомнить тот url, с которого совершен переход. Таким образом, если, например, находясь на странице 3 пагинации, при нажатии на кнопку 2 пагинации вы запомните текущий url с помощью pushState, то при нажатии кнопки "назад" в браузере пользователь вернётся на вашу страницу пагинации номер 3.

Понятно, что при этом url страниц пагинации должны различаться, что удобно, кстати, для предоставления прямого доступа к нужной странице.